# Copy specific cells from sheet to sheet based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

## 'Sub CopyRowToSheet23()

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:E1000").Clear
Dim LastRowSheet1, LastRowSheet2 As Long
Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LastRowSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:E" & LastRowSheet2).ClearContents
LastRowSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 2 To LastRowSheet1 Step 1
        If Cells(i, "E").Value = "YES" Then
            LastRowSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Rows(i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & LastRowSheet2 + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheet3.Select
```

End Sub'

I´ve managed to create the code above to get all rows that have "yes" in column E. However, I´m having issues when trying to run the macro in other sheets different than Sheet1. I would like to run it in sheet3 but I haven´t found why it does not help.

Comment: You might benefit from reading [ask] and 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim wsRE As Long, i As Long, LastrowC As Long, LastrowE As Long, LastrowF As Long

    'Set ws1
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Set ws2
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    wsRE = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    'Starting from Row 2 - let us assume that their is a header
    For i = 2 To wsRE
        'Check if the value in column E is yes
        If ws2.Range("E" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
            'Find the Last row in Sheet1 Column C
            LastrowC = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            'Copy row i, Column A from Sheet 1 and paste it in Sheet 2 after the lastrow in column C
            ws2.Range("A" & i).Copy ws1.Cells(LastrowC + 1, 3)
            'Find the Last row in Sheet1 Column E
            LastrowE = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            'Copy row i, Column B from Sheet 1 and paste it in Sheet 2 after the lastrow in column E
            ws2.Range("B" & i).Copy ws1.Cells(LastrowE + 1, 5)
            'Find the Last row in Sheet1 Column F
            LastrowF = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
            'Copy row i ,Column C from Sheet 1 and paste it in Sheet 2 after the lastrow in column F
            ws2.Range("C" & i).Copy ws1.Cells(LastrowF + 1, 6)

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi error 1004, Many thanks for replying! highly appreciated! However, when I copy your code in VBA and I tried to run it, it does not populate anything in "sheet 2". It does not show any error message either.

Comment: I´ve actually managed to create a code that copies all rows with "yes" in E column. See code below: